# Proving the inequality $\frac{\log (1)}{1!}+\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2!}+\frac{\log^3(3)}{3!}+\cdots> \frac{\pi }{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How to prove  this inequality?  $$\frac{\log (1)}{1!}+\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2!}+\frac{\log^3(3)}{3!}+\cdots> \frac{\pi }{4}$$

---

The left side looks vaguely like  the series for $\exp(x)$: the terms starting from $n$th contribute at least as much as the corresponding terms of the    series for $\exp(\log n)$. But for the preceding terms, the inequality goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: Note that $e^x - 1 = \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots$.

Comment: Very curious. the LHS is only 0.03% larger than $\pi/4$.

Comment: **@dalastboss:** and so ? I would be interested to see how you can conclude.

Comment: Easily enough with a computer, it converges pretty rapidly.

Comment: This might be blasphemous, but what's wrong with computing an upper bound for the error after truncating the $n^{\text{th}}$ term (which is easy) and then just computing the series for a sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Given the fact that their difference is about $\dfrac2{7301}$, I doubt that there's an easy way to prove this.

Answer (score 11):

As @user2345215 and @Mr.G said in the comments, to answer the question as posed is quite simple.
$$
\frac{\log (1)}{1!}+\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2!}+\frac{\log^3(3)}{3!}+\cdots
> \sum_{n=2}^{11} \frac{\log^n(n)}{n!}>0.7855>
 \frac{\pi }{4}
$$

Comment: There's got to be a less arbitrary proof - the numbers are so close!

Comment: Why the community wiki? IMO your answer isn't that bad (-: +1)

Comment: @nbubis The existing answer is perfect. The question however is idiotic. By the way $\frac{5\sqrt2}{9}$ gives two more significant digits than $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so asking about less arbitrary proof and 35 upvotes are also... a bit arbitrary.